# Invalid constant value in extended class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The following code snippet displays some styled `TextField`s in a flutter app:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Some input form')),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
            child: Column(
          children: const [
            Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 200, fallbackWidth: 200),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Label0')),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Label1')),
          ],
        )));
  }
```

Because I want all my TextFields to look the same I thought of doing this:

```
class mTextField extends TextField{
  const mTextField({Key? key, String? hint}) : super(key: key, decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: hint));//this line gives the error
}
```

To remodel my original code as

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Some input form')),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
            child: Column(
          children: const [
            Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 200, fallbackWidth: 200),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            mTextField(hint: 'Label0'),//simplified here
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            mTextField(hint: 'Label1'),//simplified here
          ],
        )));
  }
```

But this gives me an "invalid constant value" error for the `labelText: hint`. Of course I could just make the `children` of the `Container` non-const, but as far as I see it, it should be possible to have `mTextField` be constant because it is no different from a regular `TextField` which can be `const`.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` giving the error is the `const` in the mTextfield not the `Column` children. You can remove the `const` in the mTextField

```
class mTextField extends TextField{
 mTextField({Key? key, String? hint}) : super(key: key, decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: hint));//this line gives the error
}
```

Although this will cause the `Column` const to give the error. You can convert your `mTextfield` to be built like this instead

```
        class mTextField extends StatelessWidget{
     const mTextField({Key? key, this.hint}) : super(key: key);
      
      final String? hint;
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: hint));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
class mTextField extends TextField{
  const mTextField({Key? key, String? hint}) : super(key: key, decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: hint));//this line gives the error
}
```

to

```
class mTextField extends TextField{
  mTextField({Key? key, String? hint}) : super(key: key, decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: hint));//this line gives the error
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes but then the `children` of the `column` can no longer be marked `const`. Sorry, I should have stated this but I wanted to keep this const / think it should be possible.